# Windows 8.1 and EFI, recovery partition deleted, can't boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, efi, recovery-partition

I have a Windows tablet PC (Odys Winpad) with 32GB HDD. I have created recovery USB disk and deleted the recovery partition (I wanted to win some more space). Now I can't boot any more: every time I boot my PC - I get a blue screen with "Recovery" headline. EFI partition is present on my HDD, I deleted only the recovery partition.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new usb installation drive containing windows 8.1 and perform an installation. Later restore from the recovery drive created earlier. 
Can you share a screenshot of the blue screen error.